# How to show ImageView Over Background programatically

Tags: android

```
relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
setContentView(relativeLayout);

img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);

img1.setLayoutParams(parms);
setContentView(img1, parms);
```

(Part of them)

I set a default background and want to change this `b.png` after 5 seconds. These lines are in after 5 secs handler method. The above 2 lines make me see new `b.png` at background. But there is an error when I set imageview over it. I also tried `ImageView` by adding on xml at origin and to appear as view.visible. But it can't. Only background image is available and no overlapping image on it is denied.

Comment: Your question is kind of hard to udnerstand, what exactly are you trying to do? You do know that calling `setContentView()` twice won't paste to images/views above each other, right?

Comment: yes, i m trying to write 2 setcontentview() in a method. Is it not work ??

Comment: the exactly i m doing is. I set default background at xml.
And Change it to another b.png at main activity at start.
And I want to set imageview over the new background.
When i set imageview the background is invisible and get black (only imgview visible) .. Please Help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);

    relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b); 
    setContentView(relativeLayout);

    img1.setImageResource(R.drawable.d); 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);

    img1.setLayoutParams(parms); 
    relativeLayout.addView(img1, parms);
}
```

Comment: Thank You bro, visible img1 but there is a black background under it. Background i set isn't able to visible. Please advice me to get an image over a background ... Thank you So much !!
http://postimg.org/image/pd6690pf7/722dd9ff/

Comment: What kind of drawable are you using for?

Comment: Thank you for ur kindness .. I'm really dull ... I can't ... But u mean i can see imgv on relativelayout only by relativeLayout.addView(img1, parms);
Not by
contentview() ??

Comment: Yes, when you call setContentView the second time it rewrites previosly view and in your case you can see only ImageView in the screen.